# third party api for GWT

Tags: java, gwt, toolkit

I'm trying to use mail.ru java api in my GWT application, but I keep getting the same error all the time: import cannot be resolved.
I tried to add source path to the gwt.xml file, but it didn't help. any suggestions?

Comment: no, it's an api from russian social network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to use mail.ru api with client side of GWT. That's not going to work because all client side java code will be compiled to javascript and it is not usually possible with third party apps (unless specially designed) as client side in GWT only can use subset of Java that GWT compiler knows about.

Most likely what you will need to do is to use your email API in server side of GWT RPC or some other server component and then design your client code to communicate with it to send e-mail.

Comment: yup, that was the problem. Thanks a lot!